# Getting start of month and end of month with time for December

Tags: swift, date, datetime, nsdateformatter

As the title indicates I'm trying to get the start and end of month with a time component for December. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious related to TimeZones but I can't seem to get a same year for both dates in in PST time zone.

Here's how I get the start of month and day:

> NOTE: If you try this in the swift REPL there's a bug that shows nil result even though the
> variables have a non-nil value, use `print` or `debugPrint` to show the value.

```swift
let cal = Calendar.current
let startOfMonth = cal.startOfDay(for: cal.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 12, day: 1))!)
```

Here's how I calculate the end of day up to seconds:

```swift
let startOfNextMonth = cal.date(byAdding: DateComponents(month: 1), to: startOfMonth)!
let endOfMonth = cal.date(byAdding: DateComponents(second: -1), to: startOfNextMonth)!
```

By this point `startOfMonth` has the value: `Optional(2020-12-01 08:00:00 +0000)` and `endOfMonth` has a value of `Optional(2021-01-01 07:59:59 +0000)`

Which seems fine and dandy because times are printed in GMT (UTC) and if I subtract 8 hours `endOfMonth` it would end up like `Optional(2020-12-31 23:59:59 +0000)`

However the trouble comes when formatting the `endOfMonth` date, even If I set the TimeZone to `"America/Los_Angeles"` I still get the year value as `2021` and not as `2020`, here's how I create my formatter:

```swift
let fmt = DateFormatter()
fmt.timeZone = .current // "America/Los_Angeles"
fmt.dateFormat = "d/Y"

fmt.string(from: endOfMonth!) // $R13: String = "31/2021"
```

What's going on?, wouldn't conversion to the default Time zone yield the year 2020?

Comment: There are always many of those questions on turn of the year because the *misuse* of the `Y` year specifier has no effect in the rest of the year 

Answer (score 0):

After setting the formatter `dateStyle` property to `.long` and obtaining the correct year printed (though not the format I wanted) I realized that the issue might be in the `dateFormat`.

After reading a bit more of the documentation, I found a link to the format specifiers

- [Date Format Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413514-dateformat)
- [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)
- [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns)

Eventually I found out that the `Y` specifier is essentially a "Week of Year" vs the `y` specifier which is "Year of Era".

Using the following fixed my issue:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d/y"
formatter.string(from: endOfMonth!) // $R1: String = "31/2020"
```

Comment: If you want a fixed date format you should set the locale to "en_US_POSIX". From the docs: **If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results regardless of both user and system preferences.**